# kdb q - license not found despite $QHOME set

Tags: java, bash, shell, kdb, q-lang

In `.bashrc` and `.profile` I have my `QHOME` variable set to the directory that contains `k4.lic`, `l64`, `q.k` (validated by `echo $QHOME`).

When I startup q from the login shell all works fine, the license file is found.

When I start a q process programmaticaly from java, then I get the following output

```
[13:43:48][Step 1/2]  WARN [main] (QSession.java:78) - Q Session not alive
[13:43:48][Step 1/2]  INFO [main] (QSession.java:97) - QHOME: null
[13:43:48][Step 1/2]  INFO [main] (QSession.java:98) - QLIC: null
[13:43:48][Step 1/2] ERROR [main] (QSession.java:101) - Error output
[13:43:48][Step 1/2] '2018.02.06T13:43:46.597 k4.lic
```

i.e. the license is not found because the `QHOME` env variable is undefined. This problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304647/system-getenv-doesnt-get-variables-defined-in-bash-profile): "`.bashrc` is only sourced in a login shell". The proposed solution is

> "If you want a variable to be set in all Bourne shell derivatives regardless of whether they are interactive or not, put it in both .profile and .bashrc."

But I have already copied the content of `.bashrc` into `.profile` and still get the same error.

Unfortunately, there is no way to pass the path to the license as a command line argument for the `q` binary, so I have to work with `QHOME`.

What I could do is put a 32-bit version in my java project but obviously it is advantageous to use the 64-bit version.

Suggestions much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are using something like the Java `exec` method to run the Q process, I think you should adjust the command you are running to include the `QHOME` variable e.g. `exec("QHOME=/path/to/licence q")` instead of `exec(q)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Jonathan McMurray! 
The exact solution is to use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, envp);
```

where `command` is for example `q -p 5000` and `envp` is for example

```
String[] envp = {"QHOME="+qHomePath};
```